# How to create a custom DOM event?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, dom, google-tag-manager

How to create a custom js event that fire a GTM trigger. I'm using Ninja Popup plugin and I need to fire a tag when a user subscribes through the newsletter form on that popup, luckily that plugin has a JS hooks which may help in such a thing but I'm not sure what to write into it, so I can call the event name on the GTM custom event trigger. Please check the screenshot.

https://snag.gy/LtMS3C.jpg

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: As @HynekS pointed out, already a nice tutorial regarding DOM events on mdn. This question should be closed. As I'm sure it's already a duplicate of somethign else.